# Does company email can access hangouts and private emails?

Tags: email

I'am curious whether the administrator's has the privilege to access the hangouts chat and the email of employees?

For example, here in our company we are using the gmail as our private email provider. Then we can also use google hangouts, send email to other employees.

If by any chance they can monitor or access, please explain it to me in details. :)

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65766/can-my-it-department-read-my-google-hangouts-chats-while-at-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they can administer the machine, then they can monitor whatever they want from the technical point of view. They will need to put effort in to do so, but it is technically feasable. There might even be features provided by Google to access someone's account or reset the email account's password.

From a privacy law perspective it will depend on where you live, but most of the time it is not allowed. However your company may have a clause in your contract that they are allowed to perform monitoring in an automated way (limited human interaction).

Answer (score 2):

If it is company administered, there is a very good chance that they can monitor anything you do.

Comment: Hello, I added more information. I'm also seeking for the explanation please.

Comment: @CaryBondoc - An `Administrator` more then likely can access your Google account associated to your company for a variety of reasons.